# Find set of all complex numbers z such that arg(z^{3})=3arg(z) holds in some branch of arg(z).

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was given to find a branch where we will get arg(i^{3})=3arg(i) and arg((i-1)^{3})=3arg(i-1). However, I solved those problems but is it possible to find a branch for each complex number z, where we will get arg(z^{3})=3arg(z)?

Comment: Can you explain how you got the solutions to the questions you answered?

Answer (score 1):

Not all numbers have this property. Let's fix notation and call a branch $\arg_\xi$(z) if the branch cut is the ray with angle $\xi$, measured in radians from the positive real axis. Any such branch has range the interval $[\xi, \xi+2\pi)$. If $\arg_\xi(z^3)$ is supposed to be $3 \arg_\xi(z)$, this means that both of the values $\arg_\xi(z)$ and $3\arg_\xi(z)$ need to fit in the interval $[\xi, \xi+2 \pi)$. This is possible for numbers $w$ where some branch of $\arg(w)$ is smaller than $2\pi/3$ in absolute value, and not possible otherwise.